# Фабричный метод и анонимные классы

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Разбираюсь с абстрактными классами в java и в качестве примера их использования приводиться фабричный метод, и говориться что в данном случае мы можем не создавать именованный экземпляр класса что собственно делает синтаксис более осмысленным, вот пример кода:

```
interface Service{
  void method1();
  void method2();
}

interface ServiceFactory{
  Service getService();
}

class Implementation1 implements Service{

  private Implementation1(){

  }
  public void method1(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion1 print method1");
  }
  public void method2(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion1 print method2");
  }

  public static ServiceFactory factory =
    new ServiceFactory(){
      public Service getService(){
        return new Implementation1();
      }
    };
}

class Implementation2 implements Service{

  private Implementation2(){

  }

  public void method1(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion2 print method1");
  }
  public void method2(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion2 print method2");
  }

  public static ServiceFactory factory =
    new ServiceFactory() {
      @Override
      public Service getService() {
        return new Implementation2();
      }
    };
}

class  Factories{
  public static void serviceConsumer(ServiceFactory fact){
    Service s = fact.getService();
    s.method1();
    s.method2();
  }
}

public class AbstractClass {
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    Factories.serviceConsumer(Implementation1.factory);
    Factories.serviceConsumer(Implementation2.factory);
  }
}
```

Не понятно, чем это лучше на практике чем следующий код:

```
interface Service{
  void method1();
  void method2();
}
class Implementation1 implements Service{

  public void method1(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion1 print method1");
  }
  public void method2(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion1 print method2");
  }
}

class Implementation2 implements Service{

  public void method1(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion2 print method1");
  }
  public void method2(){
    System.out.println("Implementetion2 print method2");
  }
}

class  Factories{
  public static void serviceConsumer(Service s){
    s.method1();
    s.method2();
  }
}

public class AbstractClass {
  public static void main(String[] arg){
    Factories.serviceConsumer(new Implementation1());
    Factories.serviceConsumer(new Implementation2());
  }
}
```

В первом случае в Factories.serviceConsumer мы передает конкретное поле конкретного класса, почему бы не передавать сразу объект как во втором случае, к тому же во втором случае кода нужно писать меньше.

Comment: Не важно что передавать в фабрику, важно то что получается.

Comment: ну а выигрыш то в чем, кода больше результат такой же

Comment: Глворится, где говорится? В некоторых случаях не требуется создавать экземпляр класса, но этот случай очень редкий, и ничего общего к твоему вопросу не имеет. Если ты передавать объект в фабрику собрался, то это уже не фабрика а инекция

Answer (score 0):

> В первом случае в Factories.serviceConsumer мы передает конкретное поле конкретного класса, почему бы не передавать сразу объект как во втором случае

Чтобы сразу передать объект, как во втором случае, нужно сначала его создать и проинициализировать, в вашем пример это просто вызов конструктора, но на практике это может быть сложная процедура, с различной логикой для различных реализаций `Service`, так что если эту логику отдать клиентскому классу (`AbstractClass`), то получим сильную связь между этими классами, что в дальнейшем будет дорого поддерживать.

Фабричный метод как раз позволяет делегировать создание объекта другому классу, а клиентский класс не должен ничего знать о том, как создавать тот или иной экземпляр сервиса.